# int array to JPG file

Tags: java, android, файлы

Загоняю массив int значений в файл, который представляет собой фото с расширением *.jpg

```
File newFile = aFile;
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
for (int i = 0; i < icon.length; i++)
{    
       file.write(icon[i]); // icon[i]- int value
}
file.close();
```

Проблема в том, что OS андроид не определяет созданный файл как картинку и дает ему пустую иконку (как для неопределенного файла), в то время для других файлов (jpg, png и т.п.) вместо иконки дается уменьшенное изображение самой картинки. Также данный файл не открывается в галерее - стандартным приложением на планшете. В тоже время, если выбрать в пункте меню 'открыть файл как изображение' - он открывается в стандартном окне просмотра, также файл спокойно открывается в сторонней программе для просмотра изображений.

Не могу сообразить, что забыл указать при сохранении в файл.

Comment: а почему массив int? развер jpg не объязательно кратен 4, а концовку Вы никак не обрабатываете. Я бы хранил в массиве byte.

В любом случае, можете выложить картинку, сохраненную таким способом куда нибудь, что бы ее можно было посмотреть изнутри.

Comment: [`OutputStream.write(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write-int-) пишет в файл только младшие 8 бит (1 байт) аргумента, возможно в этом проблема. Попробуйте завернуть `file` в `DataOutputStream` и вызвать [`writeInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt-int-). Это тоже может не решить проблему, т.к. может быть не тот порядок записи (writeInt пишет старшие байты вперед). Как вы получаете массив для записи?

Comment: 1.ссылка на тестовый файл: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/MXps/uMubXUkYX

Comment: 2-Я бы тоже хранил byte, но вебсервис написан на C# и возвращает данные в виде "[255.0, 216.0, 255.0,......., 217.0]" ;  3-DataOutputStream - попробую поковыряться, если получится отпишусь.

Comment: DataOutputStream - размер файла увеличился в 4 раза + файл теперь вообще ничем не открывается.

Comment: Изменил немного код получения данных, но по сути ничего не поменялось - открывается только сторонней программой : `код` byte[] base64 = Base64.decode(res.Contents.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT); File newFile = aFile; FileOutputStream file2 = new FileOutputStream(newFile); file2.write(base64); file2.close(); `код`

Comment: На всякий случай спрошу: расширение файла указано верно? Папка, в которую сохраняете, доступна для индексирования? Не содержит `.nomedia` сама и выше по иерархии? Если попытаться с помощью вашего метода перезаписать картинку, из файла который уже корректно распознаётся системой в него же, результат тот же?

Comment: папка: `код` String folder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + General.MAIN_FOLDER + "/" + General.SUB_MAIN_FOLDER_OBJECT_FILES; `код` В MAIN_FOLDER имеются др подпапки где сохраняются фото/видео сделанные камерой планшета через мое приложение, они доступны и вполне читаемы.